# setting x position to the UITablecell in UITableView

Tags: ios, uitableview

I have `UITableview` in that i'm going to load custom table cells.By default cell co-ordinates at zero position but i need place  it at my required position (i.e.,30,0)
i have written  code like this::

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    NSLog(@"tableView willDisplayCell");
     CGRect frame = cell.frame;
    frame.origin.x = 30;
    frame.size.width = 250;
    cell.frame = frame;  
}
```

for first time  Table cell
 is  not loading at mentioned position after reloading it is working  fine thanks in advance

Comment: Decrease the width of the UITableView on your xib to 250, and change the X position to 30 in Xib only, no need to reset the frame of a cell..

Comment: but the x position of tableViewCell  Xib is not editable?

Comment: I think @iphonic means to set the frame of the table (both size and origin) and not change the cell frame at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't change the frame of the cell. Instead, make the cell background whatever colour your overall background is (maybe transparent) and add a view of your desired size as a subview of the cell `contentView`. Then add all of your content to this view.